# How to set up basic auth in rest code-igniter API?

Tags: codeigniter

**How to set up OAuth in rest code-igniter API?**
I have used the link

But i didn't get a solution.

[enter link description here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter--net-8814)

Comment: be specific to ur problem

Comment: I need to use OAuth in rest-codeigniter API.I didn't  get a solution.

Comment: follow CI forum this might help you http://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-13941.html